# How to create post request with Koa nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, koa-router

I have just started with the `Koa` and made a basic setup with the following code

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

// logger

var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set our port

// response

app.use(async ctx => {
  console.log(ctx.query)
  ctx.body = 'Hello World';
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Now when I hit the request `http://localhost:8080` I get the request inside the console of `ctx.query`.

**Question**: How can I make a `post` and the `get` request with the koa framework?

**Edit**: I have now implemented Koa-router

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const koaBody = require('koa-body');
const router = require('koa-router')();
const app = new Koa();
app.use(koaBody());
// logger

router.get('/users', koaBody(),
  (ctx) => {
    console.log(ctx.request.query);
    // => POST body
    ctx.body = JSON.stringify(ctx.request.body);
  }
)

router.post('/user', koaBody(),
  (ctx) => {
    console.log('dfssssssssssssssssssssss');
    console.log(ctx);
    // => POST body
    // ctx.body = JSON.stringify(ctx.request.body);
  }
)

var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set our port
app.use(router.routes());
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Still the problem is same. I can make a `get` request but not the `post` one.

Comment: use koa-router: https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-router

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use koa-router

```
var Koa = require('koa');
var Router = require('koa-router');

var app = new Koa();
var router = new Router();

router.get('/', (ctx, next) => {
  // your get route handling
});

router.post('/', (ctx, next) => {
  // your post route handling
});

app
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods());
```

Answer (score 6):

use koa-router and the koa-bodyparser middleware

```
var Koa = require('koa');
var bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');
var Router = require('koa-router');

var app = new Koa();
var router = new Router();
app.use(bodyParser());

router
  .get('/', (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.body = 'Hello World!';
  })
  .post('/users', (ctx, next) => {
    // handle your post request here
    ctx.body = ctx.request.body;
  })
  .put('/users/:id', (ctx, next) => {
    // ...
  })
  .del('/users/:id', (ctx, next) => {
    // ...
  })
  .all('/users/:id', (ctx, next) => {
    // ...
  });
app
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods());
```

Comment: Hi How can I return the response?